# Is it possible to resolve child components per instance in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to be able to pass down a child component dynamically. The child component can differ per instance of the parent component, is there any way this could be achieved without registering global components?

Here's a quick example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// Component A
export default {
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>Some stuff...</div>
            <component-b :passed-component="passedComponent"></component-b>
        </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            passedComponent: { /* ... */ },
        };
    },
    // Note: passedComponent doesn't necessarily come from `data`
};

// Component B
export default {
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>Some more stuff...</div>
            <component-c :passed-component="passedComponent"></component-c>
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['passedComponent'],
};

// Component C
export default {
    template: `
        <div>
            <div is="passedComponent"></div>
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['passedComponent'],
    components: {
        // How can I register `passedComponent` here?
        // (it can differ per instance of `component-c`)
    },
};
```

Edit for clarity: Passing down an actual component object instead of a name would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

After you said you wanted to acutally pass down the component definition as a prop, even though I can't think of a usecase, I was intrigued to find out weither this could work.

Turns out it can be done with usging the [async component](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Async-Components) functionality.

JSFiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/rvsbccan/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <test :passed-comp="compDefToPass"></test>
</div>
<template id="test">
  <passed-comp></passed-comp>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('test', {
  template: '#test',
  props: ['passedComp'],
  components: {
    'passed-comp': function(resolve) {
      resolve(this.passedComp)
    }
  },
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'compDefToPass': {
      template: '<div>When you see this, we successfully passed down a component definition as a prop!</div>',
      ready: function() {
        console.log('Hello from a prop-passed component.')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

---

Old reply for reference:

There are only the two ways you already seem to know:

- register them globally
- import and register **all** of the *possible* components locally in component C

If the second possibility seems daunting because of the many imports, you can extract those to another module:

```
// componentBundle.js
import X from './components/X.vue'
import Y from './components/Y.vue'
// .... and so on...
export default {
  X, Y, ....
}

// component-c.vue
import componentBundle from '../component-bundle'
export default {
  components: componentBundle
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer actually sending down an object as a prop instead of a component name. Besides that the second option isn't too bad. If nothing better comes up I'll accept this post as the answer.

Comment: It *almost* works. That was actually my first implementation, but the problem is that the component only gets resolved the first time, which means it can't differ per instance.

Comment: As per my use case: I'm building a component that will be distributed in a package, and part of it has to be customisable per application. I want to be able to pass a completely custom component through. (slots won't do it since the custom component is nested quite deep)

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, since I ended up registering all the possible components with an `assign` call as the `components` value.